# Counting characters in a string or file

Tags: c, string, printf, histogram

I have the following code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "ctype.h"
/*selection sort*/
void swap(int A[], int j, int k)
{
int p = A[k];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < (k - j); i++)
{
    A[k - i] = A[k - i - 1];
}
A[j] = p;
}
/*greatest number in an array*/
int max(int A[], int N, int k)
{
int max = k, i;
for (i = k; i < N; i++)
{
    if (A[max] < A[i])
        max = i;
}
return max;
}
int count_nonspace(const char* str)    
{
 int count = 0;
 while(*str)
 {
  if(!isspace(*str++))
   count++;
 }
 return count;
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    int a[256];
    int i = 0, j = 0, count[256] = { 0 };

    char string[100] = "Hello world";
    for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
    for (j = 0; j<256; j++)
    {
        if (tolower(string[i]) == (j))
        {
            count[j]++;
        }
    }
    }
    for (j = 0; j<256; j++)
    {

    printf("\n%c -> %d \n", j, count[j]);

    }
}
```

Program is calculating the number of apperances of each character in a string. Now it prints the number of apperances of all 256 characters, whereas i want it to prinf only the character with greatest number of apperances in a string. My idea was to use the selection sort method to the array with the nubmer of apperances, but this is not working, thus my question is how to printf only the character with the greatest number of apperances in the string?

If anybody would have doubts, this is NOT my homework question.

EDIT: I've just noticed that this code printf apperances of characters begining with "j" why is that?

Comment: Can you use `qsort()`? And why are your includes relative to the c file's path? shouldn't it be `#include <ctype.h>` instead of `#include "ctype.h"`?

Comment: include is my mistake, yes i can use qsort

Comment: What is "stdafx.h"? Certainly not C.

Comment: Your inner loop is entirely superfluous. Why not `count[tolower(string[i])]++;`?

Comment: Because it's default header when using Visual Studio 2013, nevertheless the code as it is is working correctly

Comment: I've just noticed that this code printf apperances of characters begining with "j" why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I started typing this before the others showed up, so I'll post it anyway.  This is probably nearly the most efficient (increasing efficiency would add some clutter) way of getting an answer, but it doesn't include code to ignore spaces, count characters without regard to case, etc (easy modifications).

```
most_frequent(const char * str)
{
    unsigned        counts[256];
    unsigned char * cur;
    unsigned        pos, max;

    /* set all counts to zero */
    memset(counts, 0, sizeof(counts));
    /* count occurences of each character */
    for (cur = (unsigned char *)str; *cur; ++cur)
        ++counts[*cur];

    /* find most frequent character */
    for (max = 0, pos = 1; pos < 256; ++pos)
        if ( counts[pos] > counts[max] )
            max = pos;

    printf("Character %c occurs %u times.\n", max, counts[max]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, maybe you can answer my question, becasuse i've noticed that my primary code is counting the numbers only from the "j" letter upwards? I am just curious why is that.

Comment: All the array traversals in your original code appear to start at zero, so I don't see any reason why it would start at `j` - either the variable or the character.  You have multiple implementations of some operations in your example, though - where are you seeing this behavior?

Comment: I see the logic is same as mine isn't it?

Comment: This behavious appears after i press "start debugging" in visual studio 2013 and still what is shown starts from "j"

Comment: The way to find that is to distill your code down to the smallest and simplest example that displays the unwanted behavior.  Usually, in the process of doing that, you;ll see the problem, but if you don't then post that code and see what people find.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create an array with your char as index.
2. Keep incrementing the value in the array based on the characters read.
3. Now get the max out of the array which gives you the most occurring char in your input.

Code will look like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
int main(void) {
    char buf[100];
    int i=0,max =0,t=0;
    int a[256];
    memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
    fgets(buf,100,stdin);
    buf[strlen(buf)-1] = '\0';
    while(buf[i] != '\0')
    {
        a[(int)buf[i]]++;
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        if(a[i] > max)
        {
            max = a[i];
            t = i;
        }
    }
    printf("The most occurring character is %c: Times: %d",t,max);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there a different method that will not use an array?

Comment: @Krowskir IMO this is the efficient way to do since you have a count in one array

Comment: Could you tell me why my primary code printf's only the character from "j" upwards?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution for that, based on your own solution, and using `qsort()`.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Frequency
{
    int character;
    int count;
};

int compare(const void *const lhs, const void *const rhs)
{
    return ((struct Frequency *)rhs)->count - ((struct Frequency *)lhs)->count;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    struct Frequency count[256];

    memset(&count, 0, sizeof(count));

    char string[100] = "Hello world";
    for (i = 0 ; i < 100 ; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0 ; j < 256 ; j++)
        {
            count[j].character = j;
            if (tolower(string[i]) == j)
            {
                count[j].count += 1;
            }
        }
    }
    qsort(count, sizeof(count) / sizeof(*count), sizeof(*count), compare);

    /* skip the '\0' which was counted many times */
    if (isprint(count[1].character))
        printf("\nThe most popular character is: %c\n", count[1].character);
    else
        printf("\nThe most popular character is: \\%03x\n", count[1].character);

    for (j = 0 ; j < 256 ; j++)
    {
        if (isprint(count[j].character))
            printf("\n%c -> %d \n", count[j].character, count[j].count);
        else
            printf("\n\\%03x -> %d \n", count[j].character, count[j].count);
    }
}
```

notice that the `'\0'` is set for all the remainig bytes in

```
char string[100] = "Hello world";
```

so the count of `'\0'` will be the highest.

You could use `strlen()` to skip `'\0'`, in the counting loop, but don't

```
for (i = 0 ; i < strlen(string) ; ++i) ...
```

do it this way

```
size_t length = strlen(string);
for (i = 0 ; i < length ; ++i) ...
```